# Download the source of an Atom Rss Feed

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I have a link that renders an rss feed, is there a way to have firefox display the source of this link as opposed to popping up the Add Live Bookmark dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every URL you can open the `view-source` version by prepending two magic words:

```
view-source:http://lebkowski.name/show/blog.atom
```

Works with any URL/Content-type. Gecko based only.

Answer (score 1):

You could lie about the Content-Type and claim that it is text/plain.

I might be slightly more inclined to create an HTML version of the source (with syntax highlighting) — but that would depend on the reasons behind you wanting non–standard behaviour.

It might be worth pointing out that Firefox 3 (at least) doesn't display a dialog, it displays an XSLTed–to–HTML version of the feed which includes a number of options (at the top) for subscribing to it. View → Source works as you would expect, so end users can easily access the source if they should so wish.